# Api empty output on client side

Tags: json, api

I am working on api of a script i recently coded. 
on browser the output of the file is working fine see here : http://www.lilink.it/api.php?u=http://www.designzzz.com/&method=get_short_url
but if i do the calling on client side it returns empty. here is the code for client side :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // method 1
    $.get('http://lilink.it/api.php', {method: 'get_short_url', u: 'http://www.blastingart.com/ayaz-malik'},

        function(data){
            alert(data.status + data.res);
        }, "json"
    );

    // method 2
    $.getJSON('http://lilink.it/api.php?method=get_short_url&u=http://www.blastingart.com/ayaz-malik', function(data) {
        if (data.status == 1) {
            alert(data.status + data.res);
        }
    });

});


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably, you are trying to make a cross-domain request. Cross domain requests are denied in modern web browsers for security reasons. But it's possible to implement them using special techniques. See:

http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: my second method as mentioned above is the same thing isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have problem about the Same Origin Policy: more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: you are correct this is the issue, i am not sure how to fix it tho

Comment: i have placed the api.php and api.js in the root of my site.. now client side calling unable to get data.